# PyQt4.QtGui causes DLL Load Error with Python 2.7.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

PyQt4 seems to work fine on Python 2.7.5 running on Windows 8 64bit until now. Using the interactive shell via `cmd`:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from PyQt4.QtGui import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

**Question:** What is causing this issue all of a sudden?

Comment: What version of PyQt did you install? Do you have 32bit or 64bit python?

Comment: I believe I installed 64bit python and 64bit PyQt. How do I check if PyQt is 32/64bit?

Comment: Reinstalled Python 64bit and it works now! Something must have overwritten by 64bit Python installation with the 32bit version :-/

Comment: From what you pasted above `MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)` it looks like it's 32bit python. If you have PyQt 64bit it would be no wonder it doesn't play along.

Comment: Would you like to post this as the answer?